# Automatically find best subnet for set of ip

Tags: algorithm, networking

How to automatically find the set subnet that best fit to the existed set IP.
I don't know what metric should use to evaluate that set subnet is better than other given set of ip. Beside, what algorithm is suit for this requirement.

Example 1:
 - Input: 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.2
 - Output: 192.168.0.2/31

Example 2:
 - Input: 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.6. 192.168.0.7
 - Output: 192.168.0.2/31, 192.168.0.6/31

Comment: This seems like a question for your teacher. As written, we'd just be guessing what you're expected to do.

Comment: yes, I'm planning to do. And find solution for this requirement

Comment: In your second example: why the output is 2 subnet and not 1 that includes all ips?

Comment: There is a section in Part 2 of [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for how to do that.